# Not able to select a dropdown using webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `http://www.makemytrip.com/`

The below is the **Html code**.

```
<div class="mrgnBot30 clearFix">
<span class="watch_icn flL"></span>
<div class="widget_inner clearFix suggest_me padBot15 flL">
<h3 class="clearFix hasBorderBottom">
<p class="clearFix checkDates">
<span class="check_date flL">
<label for="checkInDate">
Check-in Date:&nbsp;
<span id="checkInDate_day" class="dayLight">(Monday)</span>
</label>
<a id="checkInDateControl" class="cal_icn flL" href="#" tabindex="201"></a>
<input id="checkInDate" class="day flL hasDatepicker" type="text"  autocomplete="false"     value="01/21/2013"     name="searchCriteria.criterion.stayDateRanges[0].start" style="display: none;">
<span class="day date flL">
<select class="selectBox" tabindex="202" style="display: none;">
<span class="left_part flL"></span>
<span class="selectBox center_part flL selectBox-dropdown" style="display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="202">
<span class="selectBox-label">21</span>
<span class="selectBox-arrow controls flR">
<a class="select_drop_icon flR" onclick="return false;" href="#"></a>
</span>
</span>
<span class="right_part flL"></span>
</span>
<span class="day month flL">
<select class="selectBox" tabindex="203" style="display: none;">
<span class="left_part flL"></span>
<span class="selectBox center_part flL selectBox-dropdown" style="display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="203">
<span class="selectBox-label">Jan,13</span>
<span class="selectBox-arrow controls flR">
<a class="select_drop_icon flR" onclick="return false;" href="#"></a>
</span>
</span>
<span class="right_part flL"></span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="check_date last flL">
<span id="nights" class="nights flL">2 Night(s)</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here i'm having a dropdown to select a `Check in date` and `Check out date`. Frankly say, i don't know how to select a value of the dropdown from code. Moreover i am not sure weather it is a dropdown or not. why i am saying mean while recording in selenium IDE it records as `click` event for selecting a value from the dropdown.

I tried `select` statement to select a value from dropdown by catching a xpath value using `firebug`.

**The used code**:

```
 driver.get("http://www.makemytrip.com/");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[4]/a/span/span")).click();
    Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//div[2]/div/p/span/span/span[2]")));
    try {
        sel.selectByValue("21");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Nothing works. Below is the converted code from selenium IDE after the recording.

**Selenese Code:**

```
driver.get("http://www.makemytrip.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='chf_navigation']/ul/li[4]/a/span/span")).click();
assertEquals("I want to go to", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label")).getText());
assertEquals("Online Hotel Booking for Cheap, Budget & Luxury Hotels in India | MakeMyTrip.com", driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@onclick='return false;'])[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@onclick='return false;'])[3]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@onclick='return false;'])[4]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.selectBox-hover.selectBox-selected > a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@onclick='return false;'])[5]")).click();
```

Steps to see the dropdown:

1. Open http://www.makemytrip.com/
2. Click Hotels link
3. U able to see `Check in Date` dropdown.

Please provide useful suggestions to resolve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should precise that you're testing the US website. On 'worldwide', that's absolutely not the same HTML

Comment: Found it... You're testing the Emirates website...

Answer (score 0):

You have given the html code but u have not provided us the code which u have written, please provide the code u have written for this program and also let us know the error message or exception displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check in date select ids are `b_checkin_day` && `b_checkin_month`. Here is how to select them

```
//select the check-in date <select> element
Element el = driver.findElement(By.id('b_checkin_day'));
Select sel = new Select(el)
// go on with selection
```

Ckeck out select id are : `b_checkout_day` && `b_checkout_month`

That's for the US version. Indian version is definitly not a select but does not correspond to your html

EDIT : found that you were talking about Emirates website.

Sor for the day select, you should go with :

```
Element el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkInDate']/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'date')]/select"))
```

xpaths are the following for month checkIn, day Checkout && month checkout respectively

```
"//input[@id='checkInDate']/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'month')]/select"
"//input[@id='checkOutDate']/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'day')]/select"
"//input[@id='checkOutDate']/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'month')]/select"
```

Your first solution is to use these xpath to select the correct values

You can also more simply check the correct date in the inputs that are used to fill the form
i.e setting the correct date as value in

```
<input id="checkInDate" class="day flL hasDatepicker" type="text"  autocomplete="false"     value="01/21/2013"     name="searchCriteria.criterion.stayDateRanges[0].start" style="display: none;">
```

should do the trick. (note the `value="01/21/2013"`)

EDIT2 :

Have you tried to do that with the actual elements used by the visitor ? First, click on the dropdown arrow (`"//input[@id='checkInDate']/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'date')]/"`), it will make the select used by the javascript date selector visible.
You then should be able to make the good selection when clicking on : 
`//ul[contains(@class,'selectBox-dropdown') and contains(@style,'block')]//a[@rel="25"]`

if 25 is the day you want. `<ul>s/<li>s` that are used to make the selection are at the bottom of the page. Look at them, you'll find the correct xpath

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried as you said, but nothing works for me. I tried to check the element present by using `xpath as you suggest` it shows as present,but while trying to select it throw an exception as `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`. The tried code is `Select sel = new Select(
    driver.findElement(By
      .xpath("//input[@id='checkInDate']/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'day date flL')]/select")));
  sel.selectByVisibleText("28");
  Thread.sleep(5000);`

Comment: so, you'll have to throw away the `display: none;`

Comment: Please suggest how to do that from webdriver. I tried by using Javascript Executor. I'm not familiar with Java Script. So, i'm not getting the  result.

Comment: Edited with another solution